# In Unity, how to remove a RenderTexture from memory when the scene is unloaded

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, memory, textures, render-to-texture

I have a unity scene in which I do some computations with shaders and RenderTextures.

To do so, I have a script that instantiate the render texture and the material that I need and then apply the material to an existing render texture and write the result in the instanciated render texture.

Here is basically what I have:

```
public RenderTexture dstTex;
public RenderTexture srcTex1;
public RenderTexture srcTex2;
public Shader myComputeShader;
public Material myMaterial;

void Awake()
{

    //Create result render Texture
    dstTex = new RenderTexture(textureSizeX, textureSizeY, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);
    dstTex.Create();

    //Create material
    myMaterial = new Material(myComputeShader);     
    myMaterial.SetTexture("_srcTex2", srcTex2);
}

void Update()
{
    //Apply material to srcTex1 and write result in dstTex
    Graphics.Blit(srcTex1, dstTex, myMaterial);
}
```

Now this works fine. **My issue is that when I reload my scene or load another scene that uses the same script, the dstTex is not reinitialized.**

What my script does is actually updating an heighmap of the room (dstTex) with the current measured heightmap (srcTex). So the srcTex values change over time and dstTex get filled over time.

Then, when I reload my scene, I expect dstTex to be all black again since it is instanciated again with `dstTex = new RenderTexture(textureSizeX, textureSizeY, 16, RenderTextureFormat.ARGB32);`. But it is not the case, the values of the former scene are still in the texture.

I tried to add the following lines in my script to solve this but it did not work:

```
void OnDestroy()
{   srcTex1.Release();
    srcTex2.Release();  
    dstTex.Release();

    srcTex1.DiscardContents();
    srcTex2.DiscardContents();
    dstTex.DiscardContents();
}
```

Any idea on how to remove those textures from memory?

Comment: You talked about `dstTex` but is not even declared anywhere in your code....

Comment: Yes sorry it is actually also a public variable, I added it in my post. I had to write a simplier code here to explain my issue because there are a lot of other unrelated things in my code.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a definitive answer, but here are a few possible reasons your RenderTexture is not reset to all-black as you expect.

[This GameDev SE post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/71644/115296) hints that RenderTextures aren't necessarily cleared and that you should [clear it explicitly](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.Clear.html) if you want to reset the texture.

According to the [RenderTexture documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.html), when you load a new level, your RenderTexture can become lost

> Keep in mind that render texture contents can become "lost" on certain
>   events, like loading a new level, system going to a screensaver mode,
>   in and out of fullscreen and so on. When that happens, your existing
>   render textures will become "not yet created" again, you can check for
>   that with IsCreated function.

So this is the part I'm not certain on, but it seems that after reloading your scene, your RenderTexture ends up using the same hardware texture when it is re-created.

---

As for your attempted fix:

1. The documentation for [RenderTexture.Release](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.Release.html) says that it just releases the resources (and doesn't say that it is explicitly cleared):

> **RenderTexture.Release**
>
> This function releases the hardware resources used by the render
>   texture. The texture itself is not destroyed, and will be
>   automatically created again when being used.

2. The documentation for [RenderTexture.DiscardContents](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/RenderTexture.DiscardContents.html) doesn't specify an exact behavior, and that this is an optimization hint to the GPU driver:

> **RenderTexture.DiscardContents**
>
> Hint the GPU driver that the contents of the RenderTexture will not be
>   used.
>
> On some platforms, it can be good for performance if you indicate when
>   the current contents of a RenderTexture aren't needed any more. This
>   can save copying it from one kind of memory to another when the
>   texture is reused. Xbox 360, XBox One and many mobile GPUs benefit
>   from this.
>
> This call is typically only meaningful when the given RenderTexture is
>   currently an active render target. After this call, the contents of
>   the RenderTexture are undefined, so the user should not attempt to
>   access its contents before either clearing the RenderTexture or
>   drawing into each pixel of it.

Comment: I was having a memory leak with a RenderTexture and I fixed it by calling RenderTexture.Release. It seems that GC doesn't free its resources correctly even when it goes out of scope.

Comment: @rkachach Exactly this is what happens with GC. From the documentation of `RenderTexture.Release()`: ***"As with other "native engine object" types, it is important to pay attention to the lifetime of any render textures and release them when you are finished using them, as they will not be garbage collected like normal managed types."***.